# Unable to get image details from azure container registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

Unable to get image details from azure container register

I tried using azure container registry.

Can anyone assist me on this?

please let me know how to login to acr using username and password in c#?

```
        ContainerRegistryClient client = new ContainerRegistryClient(endpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential(),
         new ContainerRegistryClientOptions()
         {
             Audience = ContainerRegistryAudience.AzureResourceManagerPublicCloud
         });
        // Obtain a RegistryArtifact object to get access to image operations
        RegistryArtifact image = client.GetArtifact("kube01.azurecr.io/sensor:6", "latest");

        // List the set of tags on the hello_world image tagged as "latest"
        Pageable<ArtifactTagProperties> tags = image.GetAllTagProperties();

        // Iterate through the image's tags, listing the tagged alias for the image
        Console.WriteLine($"{image.FullyQualifiedReference} has the following aliases:");
        foreach (ArtifactTagProperties tag in tags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"    {image.RegistryEndpoint.Host}/{image.RepositoryName}:{tag}");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please let me know how to login to acr using username and password in c#?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I setup an image in the container registry with two tags through portal:

[image]

**Code:**
I tried with same code and modified some lines to get the image detail.

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Containers.ContainerRegistry;
using Azure.Identity;

string registryName = "registry1";

// Create a new instance of the ContainerRegistryClient class
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var client = new ContainerRegistryClient(new Uri($"https://{registryName}.azurecr.io"), credential, new ContainerRegistryClientOptions()
{
    Audience = ContainerRegistryAudience.AzureResourceManagerPublicCloud
});

RegistryArtifact image = client.GetArtifact("nginx","latest");

Pageable<ArtifactTagProperties> tags = image.GetAllTagProperties();

Console.WriteLine($"{image.FullyQualifiedReference} has the following aliases:");

foreach (ArtifactTagProperties tag in tags)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {tag.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Digest:{tag.Digest}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Lastmodifiedtime:{tag.LastUpdatedOn}");
}
```

**Console:**

[image]

```
registry1.azurecr.io/nginx:latest has the following aliases:
Name: latest
Digest:sha256:6650513efd1d27c1xxxxxxxxxxx
Lastmodifiedtime:15-02-2023 05:05:55 +00:00
Name: v1
Digest:sha256:6650513efd1d27c1xxxxxxxxxxx
Lastmodifiedtime:15-02-2023 06:26:16 +00:00
```

**Reference:**
[Azure Container Registry client library for .NET - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/containers.containerregistry-readme?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: for each registry i have a username and password associated with that, without providing user name and password i cannot login it gives me below error.

Comment: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)

Content:
{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"retrieving permissions failed"}]}

Headers:
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2023 07:51:05 GMT
Server: openresty
Proxy-Connection: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
X-Ms-Correlation-Request-Id: REDACTED
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-calls-per-second: REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 72

Comment: I have a username and password associated with each registry, so without username and password i can not access, please suggest how to validate is using credentials

Comment: Have you tried with above code? because I also enabled username and password in access keys but the code ran successfully.

Comment: can you share the process to create access keys?

Comment: can you let me know what are access key and how to use them?

Comment: You can get the access keys through portal, you can check this ![screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/WNxsfWW.png)

Comment: i do not have access to azure portal ACR, i only have the registry user name and password, is there a way to authenticate your registry using user name and password in visual studio.